# How to retrieve password from aws.amazon.com if lost my .pem file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to login in to the aws.amazon.com using remote desktop.For that require the password of user.I am trying to login with that but as some securities changes have been made from AWS side.So it's not working.Now to get the password i require the pem file but my client has misplaced it.

I have tried to [Resetting an Administrator password](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html) for Instance.But in step 5-d it stopping me to do this.I have attached screenshot for more.

[image]

Also I an thinking that can we convert the fingerprint key in to RSA PRIVATE KEY? As i have the fingerprint key.If I found the RSA key then i can decrypt the password.Any online creation method available to do that ?

Tried to create new instace and attaching the older volume disk though not getting password.
[image]
Anybody is facing the same issue ? If you have any solution then let me know.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I purchase the developer support and found the solution.So i think I should share over here which will save your money as well.

An alternative way to reset the password is listed below.

Use SSM[1]

- First we created the new"Recovery" IAM role adding the AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policies
- Apply that rule to your instance by right on the instance and click on "instance settings" then "Attach/Replace IAM role" Note you may need to reboot before the rule applies.

Reset Local Administrator Password:

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

2.On the left side of the page, click “Documents” then “Create Document” and paste the following JSON script into “Contents.”  Then click the Blue “Create Documents” button on the bottom right of the page.

```
{
    "schemaVersion": "1.2",
    "description": "Changes the local administrator password.",
    "parameters": {
        "Password": {
            "type": "String",
            "default": "",
            "description": "(Required) The new password for the local administrator account."
        }
    },
    "runtimeConfig": {
        "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
                    "timeoutSeconds": 60,
                    "runCommand": [
                        "",
                        "Function Reset-AdminPassword {",
                        "  Param (",
                                                "    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]",
                                                "    [string]$Password",
                                                "  )",
                                                "",
                                                "  $computer = [ADSI]\"WinNT://$($env:computername)\"",
                                                "  $users = $computer.psbase.Children | Where-Object {$_.psbase.schemaclassname -eq 'user'}",
                                                "  foreach ($user in $users) {",
                                                "    $userObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user.Name)",
                                                "    $userSID = $userObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])",
                                                "    if(($userSID.Value.Substring(0,6) -eq 'S-1-5-') -and ($userSID.Value.Substring($userSID.Value.Length-4, 4) -eq '-500')) {",
                                                "      $user.SetPassword($Password)",
                                                "      Write-Host \"Successfully changed the password for $($user.Name).\"",
                                                "    }",
                                                "  }",
                                                "}",
                        "",
                        "Reset-AdminPassword -Password {{ Password }}"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

3. On the left side of the EC2 Management Console, select “Run Commands” and click the blue “Run a Command” button. Select the document we created earlier from the list under “Command Document.”
4. Under Target Instances, select the instance for which you would like to reset the password.
5. You should be able to enter the password in the “Password” field.
6. Click the blue “Run” button on the bottom right of the screen.
7. On the next page you should see a green “Success” box showing a command ID. You can use this Command ID to keep track of the changes made by the command by clicking on it or by searching this command ID in the future under the “Run Command” section.

Comment: Work like a charm.!

Comment: Awesome answer its working more then 100%....@smit patek Th@nx for help....

Answer (score 4):

Ah! That documented process won't work if the AMI used to originally launch the instance has been deprecated (expired).

For step 5, simply select your AMI from the **AMIs** section of the EC2 management console, then choose the **Launch** command from the Actions menu. This will let you launch a new machine using the AMI you created. Make sure you choose a new keypair for which you have the `.pem` file.

Then, just continue from step 6. The general steps are:

- Stop your original instance
- Detach the boot disk ("Disk A")
- Launch another Windows instance (or use one you already have access to)
- Attach Disk A to the 2nd instance
- Update the `\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml` file on Disk A and update the `Ec2SetPassword` parameter to `Enabled` (see Step 9 on that documentation page)
- Detach Disk A from the 2nd instance and reattach it to the original instance (from Step 5 on the documentation page)
- Start the original instance and try to login

Comment: I tired it but not able to connect with new instance added another screenshot in question